# Copy on the fly text from browser and send instantaneously to a org document a list?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Basically that: as I copy (Control-C) text from the browser (Chrome), I would like those copied sentences to be sent to a ordered list in an OrgMode document:

- copied text 1
- copied text 2
- etc.

Any ideas? This would be very useful.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: I copy sentences from a website one at a time and want them to be sent to an orgmode document. I don't know how much clearer my example should be.

Comment: Sorry, I think my comment was not on point - I was actually thinking more about edge cases: What is the definition of "sentence" you have in mind? Do you need to support multiple languages? Do you actually mean bullet points or asterisks? What level of indentation should be used? Etc. I guess even a concrete example would not necessarily specify the problem at the necessary level of detail, so please forgive my original comment.

Comment: We don't need to go that deep so I get an idea of a syntax/function to use. In the general case, just an english website like this, I would select a portion of the text and sent it to an orgmode buffer.

Comment: Check out `org-protocol` in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Protocols.html#Protocols) and also the [org-protocol-capture-html](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-protocol-capture-html) repo on Github.